# OpenCV contrib / Surface Matching / Demo script wrong result / Python / Point Pair Features (PPF)

Tags: python, opencv

Installed versions:
opencv-contrib-python 4.5.4.60
opencv-python         4.5.4.58

I try to run the demo python script (ppf_load_match.py) for surface matching in the [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib). For visualization I open the scene model and the result point cloud in meshlab.
I guess both should be aligned correctly. But the alignment seems to be quite off.

Here is a screenshot from meshlab, where you can see the misalignment:
[image: screenshot]

Can you help me? As far as I have seen the alignment with the demo point clouds should be better.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daR6MC7z4uM) you can see the result I would expect.
I haven't made any changes in the [demo script](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/surface_matching/samples/ppf_load_match.py).

Comment: I think you forget to add the screenshot from meshlab, please add that

Comment: @TamilSelvan thanks! Added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Just had to change the following line/parameter.

```
results = detector.match(pcTest, 1.0/40.0, 0.05)
```

to

```
results = detector.match(pcTest, 0.5, 0.05)
```

[image: Result with changed parameter]

Have a look into this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/issues/1079), there it is explained.